# Specifying the viewer used by imshow()

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How does PIL find the viewer to use for imshow() on Ubuntu?

I notice it's trying to use "xv", but I only have "display" available
In my previous installation of Python where it correctly found "display" with no hacking from me. Any idea what environment vars/settings I need to check?

I'm Python 2.6.5, Ubuntu 10.04, PIL 1.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL finds the viewer in [`ImageShow.py`](https://bitbucket.org/effbot/pil-117/src/cad4796b9fe614febe4f581495891a7778a775e9/PIL/ImageShow.py?at=default). It uses `PATH` to search for the executable, so check to make sure `display` is on your `PATH`. You can check out the code if you want more details.

Anyway, it's possible to override PIL's choice. If you want to use `display`, use `ImageShow.register(ImageShow.DisplayViewer)`. For other viewers, subclass `ImageShow.UnixViewer`, implement `get_command_ex`, and register the new viewer class (see `ImageShow.py` for details).

Answer (score 0):

I hacked it by symlinking display to "xv" in $path